# How to adjust the time settings on an AWS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, time

When I type `date` on my AWS Linux instance, I get the time as 4 hours earlier than it is in my personal timezone.

I'd like to change this, since some logs I'm writing are showing times in the future, but I don't know how.

I can only find [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html) on the topic (other Google results appear very old), and the advice it gives is to modify the `clock` file...which I don't see existing at `/etc/sysconfig/clock`.

I am running Ubuntu.

Does anyone know how to adjust the time settings on an AWS instance?

Comment: which OS do you run ? do you have Amazon Linux instance (based on fedora family) or ubuntu like (debian) ?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on ubuntu, you can run `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` and select your region/country to change your time zone settings

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: caveat: if you change it to your local time zone, you may need to pay attention to daylight savings time issues.